# ZeroMQ (0MQ), how to connect the client to a remote server?

Tags: java, tcp, connection, zeromq, remote-server

I've implemented a simple ZeroMQ (0MQ) server and client. It works well when I use them on a machine (local). But when I run the client on one another machine, it doesn't work (it cannot connect to the remote server). I've checked my firewall and it's inactive (in Ubuntu 14.04).
My server code written in java is:

```
ZMQ.Socket responder = context.socket(ZMQ.REP);
responder.bind("tcp://*:5555");
```

and the client code:

```
requester.connect("tcp://ipaddress:5555");
```

in which "ipaddress" is the IP address of my server. 
I've tried also different port numbers.

Please, explain what is the problem and what do you suggest to solve the problem??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you `telnet ipaddress 5555` to see if you can connect to it?

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're right! There is a problem with network.

Comment: Even though telnet is insecure, it is handy as a really basic test of a TCP service.